# Connecting Extra USB HID Device to VMware Workstation VM Automatically on Startup

Tags: windows-10, usb, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

How can I connect an extra HID device (for example, an extra mouse and keyboard unifier) at VM startup for Windows 10 guest? I'm using VMware Workstation 15.0.3 on Windows 10 host machine.

I can connect non-HID USB devices like USB pen automatically to VM and VM remembers it at every start and don't connect it to host machine.

However, I cannot find an easy solution for a HID device. PC have its own mouse and keyboard. Extra HID devices will be used for guest only.

How can I do it ? Thanks.

Comment: Not at all @jamesdlin. I have a mouse controls both host and guest already. Now, I added second mouse and connect it to guest. It controls guest only. I want attach this mouse to guest permanently like a USB pen. It should connect automatically to guest at every host restart ( VM starts automatically at login).

Comment: What do you mean "Not at all"?  That is the same as the question I linked to.  You need to set `usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE"` in your VM's `.vmx` file to allow USB HID devices to be treated as generic USB devices so that you can disconnect them from the host and connect them to the VM.

Comment: I know it. I want connect extra HID to VM automatically at startup.

Comment: So can connect USB HID device to your VM, but they're just not connected when the *host* starts?  This is the sort of thing that you should clarify in your question.

Comment: Correct. The header "Connecting Extra USB HID Device to VMware Workstation VM Automatically on Startup " is clear enough  to be I think  :)

Comment: No, it isn't, because it's mentioned only in the question title.  If that were an important point, the question body needs to emphasize that and mention that you already know how to connect USB HID devices (otherwise you'll end up with answers pointing you to the question I linked to).  Furthermore, it's still unclear whether it works when the guest starts up at any other time than when the *host* starts. Your question "on startup" does not explain this.